# NSTabView prevents closing of NSSplitView subview

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, storyboard

I've got a complex application where I am using NSSplitView to create various sidebars which can be opened/shut with gravity (ie, drag the splitter bar close enough to the edge and the view closes completely) the same way XCode does it in it's UI.

Utilizing splitView(_:constrainSplitPosition:ofSubviewAt:) works great when the nested view being hidden does not contain a NSTabView / NSTabViewControllerView however if it does the window refuses to close completely leaving the tabView visible.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSSplitViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        splitView.delegate = self
    }

    @IBOutlet var splitView: NSSplitView!
    @IBOutlet var tabView: NSTabView!
    
    let gravityTolerance: CGFloat = 180.0
    
    func splitView(
        _ splitView: NSSplitView,
        constrainSplitPosition proposedPosition: CGFloat,
        ofSubviewAt dividerIndex: Int
    ) -> CGFloat {
        
        print("proposed splitter width: \(dividerIndex) => \(proposedPosition)")
        
        var retVal = proposedPosition
        
        if dividerIndex == 0 {
            if proposedPosition <= gravityTolerance {
               // tabView.isHidden = true
                retVal = 0.0
            } else {
              //  tabView.isHidden = false
            }
        }
        
        return retVal
    }
}
```

[image: blank window]

[image: works fine with empty window]

[image: tab view blocks code]

Setting the tab view as "isHidden" makes no difference and I'm pretty sure that if I hand code it all it will work fine.  But is there some simple fix ( constraints perhaps ) that I'm missing?

[image: storyboard layout]

Comment: Are you using a `NSSplitViewController`? Is "User Can Collapse" of the Split View Item switched on? Is `splitView(_:canCollapseSubview:)` implemented?

Answer (score 0):

From Willeke's comment... works like a charm.  Seems there's lots of Apple-specific support for this feature that I didn't know about: ( obviously one could get a lot fancier than this )

```
 func splitView(
        _ splitView: NSSplitView,
        canCollapseSubview subview: NSView
    ) -> Bool
    
    {
        return true
    }
```